# laravel flash message created at domain to subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

this is redirecting from www.example.com to www.admin.example.com/login

> return Redirect::route('adminLogin')->with(array('flash_message' =>
>   'Your registration was successful!!'));

On login view I have this code

> ```
> @if (Session::get('flash_message'))
>   {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
> @endif
> ```

Actually it's not showing any message. I think the problem is that the session is created on domain and showed on subdomain. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your cookies are not shared with your subdomain.

Try to update the config key `domain` in your `app/config/session.php` file and set this to `'domain' => '.example.com'`.